# Creating a new table in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

project->add new item->data->service based database->(name of DB)->add

although the DB has been created,and database and its' table's folder are in the server explorer, it is not allowing to create a new table by right clicking on table folder.It's only giving refresh and properties as options. why is that?? what can i do to crate a new table?

Comment: You'll also want to add the VS2013 tag, probably.

Comment: Thanks all. I could make it by installing data tools relevant to my visual studio version and SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the table:

1. In **Server Explorer** or **Database Explorer**, expand the **Data Connections** node, and then expand the **SampleDatabase.mdf** node.

   If the explorer for your version of Visual Studio isn't open, choose **View, Server Explorer** or **View, Other Windows, Database Explorer** on the menu bar.
2. Open the shortcut menu for **Tables**, and then choose **Add New Table**.

   The **Table Designer** opens and shows a grid with one default row, which represents a single column in the table that you're creating. By adding rows to the grid, you'll add columns in the table.
3. In the grid, add a row

Answer (score 1):

Go to sql server studio>create new query window then write script like this to create a table

```
CREATE TABLE [schema].[sampletable](
    [RecordNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID_NO] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](20) NULL
)
```